# push InputStream items into Array

Tags: java, android, arrays, sockets, inputstream

I am working on a client/server project. The client side is an android project and the server side is in a java IntelliJ project.

The client/Android side has a spinner and when the item (day of the week) is selected it sends over the string ("monday", "tuesday", ect.) to the server through a socket

```
dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
String daySelectedFromClient = dataInputStream.readUTF();
```

I need to store the item (`daySelectedFromClient`) in an array and if the item is already in the array on the server side I need to return a message saying that the item (that day of the week) is already selected. I'm having a hard time finding something on this. I'm not sure if `DataInputSteam` is the best way to achieve this and I can't seem to get them loaded into an array. Any suggestion?

its being loaded into the socket like so

```
        Socket socket = null;
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
        DataInputStream dataInputStream = null;

            try {
            socket = new Socket("192.168.56.1", 8080);
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(
            socket.getOutputStream());
            dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
            dataOutputStream.writeUTF(String.valueOf(spinner1.getSelectedItem()));
            }catch(....
```

and the values in the string.xml

```
 <string name="day_prompt">Choose a day</string>
<string name="Monday">Monday</string>
<string name="Tuesday">Tuesday</string>
<string name="Sunday">Sunday</string>
<string name="Thursday">Thursday</string>
<string name="Friday">Friday</string>
<string name="Saturday">Saturday</string>

<string-array name="day_arrays">

    <item>@string/Monday</item>
    <item>@string/Tuesday</item>
    <item>@string/Thursday</item>
    <item>@string/Friday</item>
    <item>@string/Saturday</item>
    <item>@string/Sunday</item>
</string-array>
```

Comment: You need to show how the client writes the data into the socket. Does it write anything else to that socket? Like integers or doubles? Note: it sounds like you'd do better with a `Set` rather than an array.

Comment: Your right I forget, just updated it.